# Getting Profile is missing the required UUID property error after editing my mobile.provision manually

Tags: xml, xcode, visual-studio, maui

Installing embedded.mobileprovision throws error of Profile is missing UUID property.

For adding a missing key I added manually my embedded.mobileprovision. Then after installing it throws this error.

Comment: Could you please add more information about what you did exactly? Have you created a proviso profile in the Apple Developer console and added your device UUID to the list of registered devices to it?

Comment: Does this help? [Publish an iOS app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/publish-ad-hoc?tabs=vs)